# Coin toss probability

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

How would I go about calculating the probability of the following, the number of tosses needed when tossing 3 coins for the probability of at least one head to be at least 0.99999?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm missing something about the "3 coins".  If you can solve this with one coin, isn't your question answered just by dividing that number of coins by three and rounding up (to get the number of 3 coin tosses)?

Comment: Interesting.  If you tossed a coin and it came up tails 16 times in a row, would you start to doubt the assumption that the coin in unbiased?

Answer (score 0):

You would just figure the probability of there being no heads. The probability of there being no heads on 3 coin tosses is $ \frac{1}{8}$

So to compute the number of times that can happen and satisfy your conditions:

$$ \left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^n=1-0.99999 $$

Solving for n yields about 5.6, so we round up and get 6 as the answer.